# Generating Doctrine fixture data for Nested Set entity with Alice Fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, faker, nelmio-alice

I'm using [`hautelook/AliceBundle`](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) (which uses [`nelmio/alice`](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) and [`fzaninotto/Faker`](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)) to generate fixtures for an application. I have a Doctrine entity `Group` which is a nested set entity (using the Tree functionality provided by [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)). What I can't figure out is how I can generate fixture data for the nested set entity - making sure that groups are generated as a tree with accurate root IDs and parents. Thanks for any guidance.

My current fixture file is as simple as;

```
MyBundle\Entity\Group:
  group{1..25}:
    title: <word()>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it to work by manually defining the groups for each level of the nested set like so;

```
MyBundle\Entity\Group:
  group_root{1..5}:
    title: <word()>

  group_level_1{1..50}:
    parent: '@group_root*'
    title: <word()>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your entity (in my example it will be `User`) like this

```
class LoadUserData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $admin = new User();
        $admin->setUsername('admin');
        $admin->setFirstName('John');
        $manager->persist($admin);
        $manager->flush();
        $this->addReference('test-user', $admin);
    }
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and then use it as a dependency:

```
class LoadQuestionData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $question = new Question();
        $question->setSubject('Test Question');

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getReference('test-user');
        $question->setUser($user);
        $manager->persist($question);
        $manager->flush();
    }
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

`getOrder()` - controlls wich entity will be generated first and second

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really what I'm looking for. I could manually define fixtures in YAML files and refer to other groups without needing to create PHP fixtures (which is what Alice is for anyway) but I was wondering if there was a way that Alice could handle Nested Set relationships automatically.

Comment: I do understand your question, but it was just an example how i did it.

Comment: Fair enough, I've gone with the method in my answer anyway which works as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

To build a [Binary_tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) I use this:

```
App\Entity\Group:
    group1:
        title: <word()>
        # this is the tree root, do not set a parent
    group{2..100}:
        title: <word()>
        parent: '@group<(floor($current/2))>'
```

You can of course choose sth. different than `x/2`. Just be sure to provide an integer (round, floor, ceil, ...).